# Make a cell counter that can track ticket number per hour

Tags: google-sheets

How can I make a formula that can only count the 10 digit number per single cell for each hour? Whereas the A2 would be the total and it will always add 1 to each number added per hour? Basically a live ticket counter.

[image: problem]

I used the line break method on google sheets but it also counts empty cells as one and I would like it to be as short as possible. Thanks!

I followed this formula initially: =LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1
It only counts line break per cell and I would just enclose it with parenthesis and add the next cell

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share a text based example, or, preferably, share an *editable* example sheet. Separately, please define your input **and** desired output. For example, what delineates your phrases within each cell? Simply by count of digits -- ie. every 10 digit is a new phrase? Are there anything in between digits?

Comment: Regarding:  "I followed this formula initially: `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1`", what formula are you currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the values in the cells are 10 digit numbers, you can concatenate them, take the length and divide it by 10

```cpp
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(,A2:C2),"\D",))/10
```

Another solution would be to split by the newline and return the size of the resulting array

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(TOCOL(A2:C2,1),CHAR(10))<>"")
```

Comment: Totally works! Thanks a lot!